# C# Memory Access Violation Windows 7

Tags: c#, dllimport, access-violation

I'm using advanced installer 8.3 and trying to impliment trial licensing for my application, the target OS is Windows 7 x32 & x64.

The following code is taken from an example supplied by advanced installer.

```
 [DllImport("Trial.dll", EntryPoint = "ReadSettingsStr", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern uint InitTrial(String aKeyCode, IntPtr aHWnd);

[DllImport("Trial.dll", EntryPoint = "ReadSettingsRetStr", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern uint InitTrialReturn(String aKeyCode, IntPtr aHWnd);

[DllImport("Trial.dll", EntryPoint = "DisplayRegistrationStr", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern uint DisplayRegistration(String aKeyCode);

[DllImport("Trial.dll", EntryPoint = "GetPropertyValue", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern uint GetPropertyValue(String aPropName, StringBuilder aResult, ref UInt32 aResultLen);

 private void registerToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    DisplayRegistration(kLibraryKey, process.MainWindowHandle);
  }

  catch(Exception ex1) 
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex1.ToString());
  }
}
```

The type signature set in advanced installer is 32bit unicode DEP Aware.

The problem is everytime i select register i get an Access Violation. It appears i cannot use the switch on my app to turn off DEP as it is required for my application.

Does anyone have any ideas how to get round this, as i have checked on the advanced installer forum and theres not much other than similar issues.

Many Thanks

**OK quick update.**

I tried all the combinations of the sig type this is what i found.

Setting the type to 32bit Ansi (Supports Win9x or higher) and set the CharSet to Ansi/Unicode or Auto result = CRASH.

Setting the type to 32bit Unicode (DEP Aware) and set the CharSet to Unicode or Auto result = Access Violation.

Setting the type to 32bit Unicode (DEP Aware) and set the CharSet to Ansi result = success.

So although it is working there's obviously a bug in Advanced Installer.

Comment: Why would you want to turn of DEP?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Apparently this is a [requirement](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-licensing.html) of advanced installer for x86 (ANSI) binaries "...supports Win9x or higher OS and can't be used in DEP enabled applications".

Comment: I don't fully understand, but it seems like they support two library types that are compatible with DEP.

Comment: Can you also paste the C type signatures? With the information given so far, and without seeing the C type signatures, I would try different CharSet enum values.

Comment: Now put in the C type signature, i'll try different CharSet values see if that gets past the issue. The signature i'm using is supposed to be compatible with DEP.

Comment: OK thats odd on all the imports i set the CharSet value to CharSet.None and it works, no Access Violation. Is this right setting to None.?

Comment: Did you try contacting Advanced Installer support?

Comment: The page that Christian linked clearly shows that CharSet.Ansi is required.  That is *not* enough to explain the crash, CharSet.Auto would make it see a string of one character long.  This product is clearly failing the simple smoke test, you should consider ditching it.

Comment: Actually, it is enough to explain the crash. All Advanced Installer licensing tutorials and how-to's use CharSet.Ansi because that's the function signature. Any other CharSet doesn't match the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your last comment (using `CharSet.None` fixes the problem), I would *guess* the following:

Specifying `CharSet.None`, which is the deprecated synonym for `CharSet.Ansi`, really causes P/Invoke to [marshal the strings as ANSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b93s42f.aspx), not Unicode (which would be used with `CharSet.Auto` on Windows NT platforms).

Looking at ["6. Integrate the Licensing Library within application"](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-licensing.html#section460) it looks like VB.NET (so maybe also C#) should use the "ANSI" version of the `Trial.dll` (APIs).

Or maybe there is a different version of `Trial.dll` that supports unicode, but is not the one that is in your PATH (and thus is not found by P/Invoke).

I don't know the product, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: There is an Unicode Trial.dll available. So perhaps the licensing feature is not configured correctly.